# Can we use conditions with expectedExceptions in TestNG

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, testng

I'm using TestNG. I'm having a test case which is running for both admin users as well as standard users. For admin users expected behavior is no exceptions and task get success while for standard users expected is a exception. In this kind of scenario what is the best approach?

1. Should we write 2 separate test for user ?
2. Is there a way to use
   `expectedExceptions` annotation with some condition

I can use try catch inside the method and check for the condition. But I think it is not a good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `expectedExceptions` doesn't have any additional properties (like conditions).

Just write two separate tests, one for admins and one for regular users.

Comment: Yes I agree. But isn't it duplicating same code just for 2 users?

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne test code is still code - extract the common parts to a different method and have both tests call it and add their unique behavior (expecting an exception for a regular user and presumably asserting the correct result for an admin).